# JIRA close all subtask with perticular resolution

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

How to close all subtask of a JIRA story with perticular Resolution like fixed or completed.

Looking for some script or addon which can help.

Comment: This is [off-topic (#4)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: you can do a bulk change I think